How do I keep my fragment in Android Studio from being transparent?
Rewrite this so it's appropriate for StackOverflow. As in all the code blocks will have 4 spaces in each line
So I have a fragment in my app and when I click on the button that takes me to it, it shows my fragment but it's transparent, meaning that the main page is still visible behind it and I can also click on the buttons that are in the background. How do I avoid this? I already set my button that takes me to that fragment to replace the fragment rather than add it but it doesn't work. Here's the code for the button
 settingsBtn.setOnClickListener {

            val fragment = Fragment1().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putSerializable("tankAdapter", tankAdapter)
                }
            }
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1ID, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }

Here's the code for my layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/humidity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.307" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/humidity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/locationTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temperatureTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Temperature"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027" />



    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="232dp"
        android:max="30"
        android:progress="15"
        android:rotation="270"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperatureTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Humidity"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/temperatureTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.107" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reptileTemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:text="Temp inside tank:\n"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.063"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperatureTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.921" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reptileHumid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Humidity inside tank:\n"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/reptileTemp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperatureTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.588" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adjustTemp"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tempBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mistBtn"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
        android:text="Mist"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reptileHumid"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.78" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tempBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Adjust temp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mistBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.455"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.371" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updateBtn"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="Check weather updates"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tempBtn" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

And the code for my fragment
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"

    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Please enter the temperature and humidity."
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextHumidMin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTempMin"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Temperature(Min)"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.563"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTempMax"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Temperature(Max)"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.035"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTempMin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.164" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHumidMin"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Humidity(Min)"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHumidMax"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:text="Humidity(Max)"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enterBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.967"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTempMax"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextHumidMin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.533" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enterBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Enter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.67" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instructions"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


I'm not sure what else I need to provide, I'm still new to Android Studio. But I just need to be able to actually replace the fragment rather than have it just stacked ontop with whatever's in the main page still visible/clickable.
EDITI fixed an issue (kind of), all I had to do was go to themes.xml and change it the following from parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> to parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight" Now the fragment shows the whole fragment but I can still click on the buttons in the fragment behind it.

If you gonna use fragment, make the content of the the main activity as a fragment too, and the activity contains only the frame, which display the main fragment or the second fragment. Don't overlay the frame on your main content.
